# Program not compiling

Tags: java

I am reading about inheritance and exceptions. When I try to compile the below code in console, I am getting compiler error. Still I couldn't figure out why. But if I change the method name in my class B, everything works fine. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

class A {  

    public void print() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In Class A.");
        throw new IOException("Printed in A.");
    }

}

class B extends A {

    public void print() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In Class B.");
        throw new Exception("Printed in B.");
    }

}

public class TestPrint {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        B b = new B();
        try {
            b.print();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An overridden method can not throw Checked Exception which is higher in hierarchy than original method.

`Exception` is super class of `IOException`.

So your `print()` method sub class (`B`) can throw either `IOException` or any of the sub classes of `IOException`.

Change your class `B`, as shown below:

```
class B extends A {

    public void print() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("In Class B.");
        throw new IOException("Printed in B.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't throw higher exception in inheritance hierarchy in overridden method, That is `IOException` is subclass of Exception Class.

You can throw any exception that is subclass of `IOException` in overridden method

Comment: that was written an hour ago by Gokul Nath !!